# Control Styles and Templates for Windows 8 Metro-UI

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, controltemplate

I've met some issue with the visual appearance of my C#/XAML Metro-UI application. I want to customize default template. For another type of applications, I can take default styles and controls from MSDN articles. For example:

- [Control Styles and Templates for WPF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970773%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Control Styles and Templates for Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278075%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Where can I find something similar for Metro-UI default styles and templates?

I know that is possible to extract template or style in Expression Blend. But I get the issue with my Blend for Visual Studio 11 described in the [next thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/toolsforwinapps/thread/e54e6665-ef1b-4c54-b13c-f47031f3acdb).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it!

Folder `c:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\winrt\xaml\design\` on my PC(x86) contains `generic.xaml` that has description of each default styles and controls.

Answer (score 2):

ThemeResources.xaml contains the resource dictionaries for the Dark (Default), Light and HighContrast themes while Generic.xaml contains the default styles and templates for most of the xaml controls.