# How to change a ListBox selected item background to an image?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox, windows-phone

I have this listbox:

```
 <ListBox Name="lstEmployee" 
                 FontSize="32" 
                 SelectionChanged="lstEmployee_SelectionChanged" 
                 Margin="10,60,10,78" 
                 Grid.RowSpan="2"
                 Foreground="#FF3F575D">
```

and it is being filled this way:

```
 foreach (var contactdata in RootObject_1.results)
                {

                    StackPanel stk = new StackPanel();
                    stk.Name = "stack" + ctr.ToString();
                    stk.Orientation = System.Windows.Controls.Orientation.Vertical;
                    stk.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;

                    TextBlock txtBlk = new TextBlock();
                    txtBlk.Name = "txtBlk" + ctr.ToString();
                    txtBlk.Text = contactdata.name;
                    txtBlk.FontSize = 30;
                    txtBlk.FontWeight = System.Windows.FontWeights.Bold;
                    txtBlk.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
                    txtBlk.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

                    TextBlock txtBlk1 = new TextBlock();
                    txtBlk1.Name = "txtBlk" + ctr.ToString();
                    txtBlk1.Text = contactdata.formatted_address;
                    txtBlk1.FontSize = 22;
                    txtBlk1.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Center;
                    txtBlk1.TextWrapping = TextWrapping.Wrap;

                    stk.Children.Add(txtBlk);  // index 0  
                    stk.Children.Add(txtBlk1);  // index 1  
                    lstEmployee.Items.Add(stk);

                    referenceList.Add(contactdata.reference.ToString());

                }
```

How can I change the selected item background with an image?
    ("\Image\Taxi\800\cellselect_800")

**UPDATE**

To make JSON Request I'm using this:

```
void chamaTaxi()
    {

        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_DownloadStringCompleted);
        webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?&query=taxi&location=-19.94549444,-43.92314218&&radius=5000&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDucC8QBV5wu4V-dQXFfABXGaaUzdmT5xw"));

    }
void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>
         {

                var RootObject_1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject_1>(e.Result);

               **code above**
    }
}
```

For JSON classes I use this link:[JSON URL](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?&query=taxi&location=-19.94549444,-43.92314218&&radius=5000&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyDucC8QBV5wu4V-dQXFfABXGaaUzdmT5xw) and this generator: [generator](http://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: I would suggest using a `DataTemplate` for you data rather than dynamicly creating the `ListBoxItem`, this way you could just bind you Results to the `listbox` and add the backgroun image.

Comment: But using DataTemplate can I still fill the listbox dynamicly? Because the contactdata is coming from a json request, and the number of results may vary.

Comment: Yes, it will work with any amount of results, if you show what your `contactdata` class looks like I can show you an example.

Comment: I was trying to put the code in comments, now it is in the question.

Comment: I have the same problem... Oo

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick MVVM example of doing this using DataTemplate

Create a `ObservableCollection` to hold your data model and populate the list with your data and the `DataTemplate` will display the Data onscreen.

In the `DataTemplate` there is an `Image` that will be `Visible` only when the Item is selected

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication8.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Name="UI">

    <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=UI}" >
        <ListBox  ItemsSource="{Binding ContractDataList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
            <ListBox.Resources>
                <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVisibleConverter" />
            </ListBox.Resources>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Image Source="Image\Taxi\800\cellselect_800.png" Stretch="Fill" Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibleConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}}}"/>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Address}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication8
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private ContractModel _selectedItem;
        private ObservableCollection<ContractModel> _contractDataList = new ObservableCollection<ContractModel>();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            //foreach (var contactdata in RootObject_1.results)
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
            {
                var model = new ContractModel
                {
                    Name = "name" + i,
                    Address = "address" + i,
                    Reference = i.ToString()
                };
                ContractDataList.Add(model);
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ContractModel> ContractDataList
        {
            get { return _contractDataList; }
            set { _contractDataList = value; }
        }

        public ContractModel SelectedItem
        {
            get { return _selectedItem; }
            set { _selectedItem = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem"); }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }


    public class ContractModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _name;
        private string _address;
        private string _reference;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return _name; }
            set { _name = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Name"); }
        }

        public string Address
        {
            get { return _address; }
            set { _address = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Address"); }
        }

        public string Reference
        {
            get { return _reference; }
            set { _reference = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("Reference"); }


        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this,
                    new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: It is showing an error in AncestorType, in ImageSource properties, i need to put some Assembly Reference?

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd have to modify the ListBoxItem's control template.  Three steps:

1) Locate the default control template for `ListBoxItem` -- [should be found in this directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10861160/1001985):

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Kits\8.0\Include\winrt\xaml\design
```

2) Insert your image into the control template (wherever you want it to appear), and hide it initially with opacity=0:

```
<Image x:Name="image" Source="Images/Taxi\800\cellselect_800" Opacity="0" />
```

3) Add an entry to the storyboard under `VisualState x:Name="Selected"`.  This will show the image when the item is selected:

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Duration="0" To="1"/>
```

Comment: I'm trying to edit it but is showing access denied message when I try to save it.

Comment: @DanielNazareth edit the file under `ProgramFiles` you mean?  Don't do that -- copy the `<Style TargetType="ListBoxItem"` section and paste it into your application resources.

Comment: I copy this, and it is showing this messages in ContentPresenter:

The member "ContentTransitions" is not recognized or is not accessible. 

The property 'ContentTransitions' was not found in type 'ContentPresenter'.

You know why?

Comment: @DanielNazareth argh ... sorry, I'm not sure about that.  If you post the code into your question, then I could take a look. (**Question**: the image is fixed, right?  It doesn't change depending on the data?  That was my assumption.)