# Simple hover effect in XAML?

Tags: css, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

So, I was recently frustrated with a challenge to copy this effect:

```
<style>
a:hover {background-color:yellow; }
</style>
```

Using the XAML implementation in WinRT.

What is the most condense solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so here's my attempt:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
        <VisualState x:Name="Hover">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation To="Yellow" Duration="0"
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                    Storyboard.TargetName="MyTextBox" />
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

<Grid x:Name="MyTextBox" Background="White"
        PointerEntered="MyTextBox_PointerEntered" 
        PointerExited="MyTextBox_PointerExited"
        Height="114" Width="537">
</Grid>
```

And this:

```
private void MyTextBox_PointerEntered(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, Hover.Name, false);
}

private void MyTextBox_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, Normal.Name, false);
}
```

But, surely there's a better way!

Comment: Ran across this while researching a hover situation on a scrollviewer. Interesting solution. :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ColorAnimation To="Yellow" Duration="0"
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Panel.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                Storyboard.TargetName="MyTextBox" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed"/>
            </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

"Hover" state in RT is "PointerOver".

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to look into Visual States and the [VisualStateManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.visualstatemanager). I think the Button control is the only one having visual states, meaning your visual entity must be defined as a Button (although it doesn't have to function as one). In the bottom of that article, you will find an example.

[This SO-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10425124/where-are-the-possible-visualstates-for-windows-8-metro-controls-documented) might also be helpful, describing how to extract the control template from an existing button. This will give you a starting point you can modify for your needs.

As for "most condense solution", I'd like to see that as well. The examples I've seen all require 20+ lines of XAML code, which to me doesn't feel very condense...

Comment: No, I don't think Button is the only control with VisualStates. If you pull up the Grid Template, they use a VisualStateManager on the main Grid to control transition between FullScreenLandscape, Snapped, Portrait, etc.