# creating WintRT XAML control : image with a text panel that slide up on mouse over

Tags: c#, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I need to create a small xaml control (for a windows 8 application / WintRT)
This control is a simple button that surround an image with a text block at the bottom of the image.
The text block should be hiddent and slide up when the user pass his mouse over the button
like in this image:

[image: sample picture]
<sub>(source: [skynet.be](http://users.skynet.be/fc471815/xaml-control.jpg))</sub>

I have the button, the image and the textblock, but I don't know how I can hide the textblock and slide it up on mouse over.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the button's ControlTemplate with an image and a text block. Use VisualStateManager and Hover state to animate TextBlock.

This might be some help:
[Simple hover effect in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160715/simple-hover-effect-in-xaml)