# Create a mouse hover effect in buttons using XAML

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am making a Windows 8 store app, and I want a `HyperlinkButton` that changes its color whenever it is clicked or mouse is hovered over it. Please provide me with its whole coding. I have looked everywhere, but none are working for my project. I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choice. Either you can customize the default style of `HyperlinkButton` or you can change the value of required default system brush (This will create effect to all `HyperlinkButton`).

System brush of `HyperlinkButton`.

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkButtonBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkButtonBorderThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkDisabledThemeBrush" Color="#66FFFFFF" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#FF9C72FF" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#CC9C72FF" />
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="HyperlinkPressedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="#999C72FF" />
```

Default Style

```
<Style TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource HyperlinkForegroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource HyperlinkButtonBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource HyperlinkButtonBorderThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{StaticResource HyperlinkButtonBorderThemeThickness}" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,4,12,5" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold" />
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource ControlContentThemeFontSize}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="HyperlinkButton">
                <Grid>
                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource HyperlinkPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource HyperlinkPressedForegroundThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource HyperlinkDisabledThemeBrush}" />
                                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                            <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                                     Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                                     To="1"
                                                     Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </VisualState>
                            <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                            <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                        </VisualStateGroup>
                    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <Border x:Name="Border"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Margin="3">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                          ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                          ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                          Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Border>
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                               IsHitTestVisible="False"
                               Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                               StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                               StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                               Opacity="0"
                               StrokeDashOffset="1.5" />
                    <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                               IsHitTestVisible="False"
                               Stroke="{StaticResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                               StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                               StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                               Opacity="0"
                               StrokeDashOffset="0.5" />
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[HyperlinkButton styles and templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj709918.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, right out of the box, here's the full implementation (Windows 8.1):

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}">Hello World</Button>
```

First, I recommend that you do not attempt to customize the colors. This helps ensure a level of visual alignment with your app and the rest of the ecosystem. So, you might tweak the look and feel by changing the theme like this:

```
<Button RequestedTheme="Dark"
    Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}">Hello World</Button>
<Button RequestedTheme="Light"
    Style="{StaticResource TextBlockButtonStyle}">Hello World</Button>
```

However, sometimes you must customize more. I get that. So, if you want to customize those colors, you will need to override the theme. Like this (in app.xaml):

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <!-- normal -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Blue" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
                <!-- hover -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPointerOverForegroundThemeBrush" Color="Red" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Transparent" />
                <!-- pressed -->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPressedForegroundThemeBrush" Color="White" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonPressedBackgroundThemeBrush" Color="Red" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Runny enough, I asked a similar question a while back [Simple hover effect in XAML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160715/simple-hover-effect-in-xaml)

Best of luck!

Comment: "RequestedTheme" is not a parameter in "Button" class. -_-

Comment: It is in Windows 8.1!

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood. I see the VS2012 tag now. Sorry.

Comment: I recommend you upgrade because the benefits are substantial.